# Node js, generated dist folder, html page included link not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, path, gulp-watch

I am using node.js + angular js in my project, i generated dist and run from dist folder on server.

Locally i am using gulp watch and run on localhost:9000 port without generating dist and it's working fine, but when i upload on server and it's get from dist, included link is not working.

I include link for auto-complete google place
here is link https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places

How can i solve this issue ?

Comment: It's not generate link beacause i include the file within bower tag,
i remove from bower tag and put it outside and it's working fine.